# Execute a sub Function on a button which is created programatically

Tags: vba, libreoffice, openoffice-calc

im rather new to VBA. MY problem is:

I create a Button when I Click another Button: the create Button is created as followed:

```
Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i +6, 4), Cells(i+6, 5)) '+6 to start at cell 6
    Set buttons =   ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top , t.Width, t.Height)
        With buttons
            .OnAction = ""  
            .Caption = "Add TestCase to  " & sReturn
            .Name = "Btn" & i

        End With
```

And I want to have an function in "OnAction". But I just doesn't Work, I receive a "Syntax Error". Basically I just want to have a function executed on a Click on a button which is created programatically. I also looked several forums for this problem and nothing worked, I think cause it is libreoffice.
Edit: the solutions work in Excel not  in Libreoffice

Comment: On what line is error? And what do you mean by "And I want to have an function in "OnAction" " ?

Comment: Hello, the error is in line .OnAction = "add_simple_Line_for_useCaseSheet"
The button creation works if I leave OnAction blank
add_simple_Line_for_useCaseSheet is a function

Comment: The error says what ? and does your function 'add_simple_Line_for_useCaseSheet ' have arguments ?

Comment: Hello, my function add_simple_Line_for_useCaseSheet is a function without parameters. it looks like 

sub add_simple_Line_for_useCaseSheet
    some Code
End sub

Comment: Please ask a complete question. Do not add many comments all over here, edit your question to make it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Excel:

Using a direct example from [here](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/18850-menu-bar-macro-parameters?t=28365):

```
Sub test()

    Dim t As Range
    Dim Buttons As Object

    Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i + 6, 4), Cells(i + 6, 5)) '+6 to start at cell 6
    Set Buttons = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)

    With Buttons
        .OnAction = "'Btn3 ""Hello"", 123'"
        .Caption = "Add TestCase to  " & sReturn
        .Name = "Btn" & i

    End With

End Sub

Sub Btn3(strString As String, iInt As Integer)
    MsgBox "String = " & strString & vbNewLine & "Integer = " & iInt
End Sub
```

Caveat:

Unable to test on Office Libre. This may be unsupported functionality.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer. I copied your example and looked on the example on ozgrid.com and I still got an error in the .OnAction line. BASIC runtime Error '1' Type: com.sun.star.uno.RuntimeException
Message: . Thats my error Message

Im using the newest  libre office. Do you think your example works in Libre office ? i have no idea why it doesn't work, every example I try results in the same result.

Comment: It may indeed be a problem with what is supported in Libre Office. What is the rest of the message?  BASIC runtime Error '1' Type: com.sun.star.uno.RuntimeException Message: .........

Comment: Hello, no there is no information besides 

BASIC runtime error.
'1'

Type: com.sun.star.uno.RuntimeException
Message: 

thats all. No further information. If I google basic runtime error 1 there is also not much information

Answer (score 1):

> im rather new to VBA... the solutions work in Excel not in Libreoffice.

So new that you do not even know what language to use!  For some reason, this seems to be a common misunderstanding.  Microsoft Excel uses VBA. 
 For LibreOffice, write in [LibreOffice Basic](https://help.libreoffice.org/Basic/Basic_Help).

Complete example code for creating buttons is at https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=27424.

A good place to start learning Basic is http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php.

Answer (score 0):

go as follows

```
    With ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
        .OnAction = "MyMacro" ' change "MyMacro" to your actual macro name
        .Caption = "Add TestCase to  " & sReturn
        .Name = "Btn" & i
    End With
```

I tested it with the following macro *attached* to the button:

```
Sub MyMacro()
    MsgBox "HellO"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, I did it that way several times. Could you show me how your "MyMacro" looks like ? maybe im missing a keyword or something.

Comment: Hello, did you test it with Libreoffice 6 ?

Comment: I didn’t. And I can’t since I don’t have it

Comment: And did your function look like
sub myNewFunction()
With ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
        .OnAction = "MyMacro" ' change "MyMacro" to your actual macro name
        .Caption = "Add TestCase to  " & sReturn
        .Name = "Btn" & i
    End With
End Sub


sry I don't know how to comment in code format

Comment: I’m not by my PC anymore, but I can tell you my Sub was like my shown code plus preceeding 1) dimming of involved variables (e.g: Dim t As Range, Dim i As Long) 2) initialization of i and setting of t range